# How to prove that $x\cdot{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}$ increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I need to show that $x\cdot{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}$ increasing for $x\in [1,\infty)$.

Of course, I derived the function and tried to show that $f'(x)>0$, but got to a dead end...

How may one show it?

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $f(x)=x(\log(x+1)-\log x)$ so $$f'(x)=\log(x+1)-\log x+ x\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac 1 x\right)=\log(x+1)-\log x- \frac{1}{x+1}$$
now by the mean value theorem
$$\log(x+1)-\log x=\frac 1 c,\quad c\in(x,x+1) $$
so we deduce easily that $f'(x)>0$ and $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you can just show that $(x+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right) > (x)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x \geq 1$.

Comment: Hence $f(x+1) > f(x), \ x \geq 1$. Nice.

Comment: I didn't manage to show it... may you help?